# What does it mean by verification in Firebase phone authentication

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an android app which uses Firebase phone authentication, so I decided to go through the pricing. It says this on the [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/):

> US, Canada, and India    $0.01/verification
>   All other countries   $0.06/verification

I would like to ask what is meant by verification,
Does it mean every time the user sign in or when an email verification is sent to the user email or any process done using Firebase.

Answer (score 2):

That's just per user verification at the time they create an account.  After that, the account works just like any other account verified by other authentication providers that don't cost anything.  You're essentially paying for the management of the SMS messaging that verifies the user's phone number.